# image transform on reference tag

Tags: image-transforms, reference-tags

Can someone tell me how to do an image transform on a reference tag? I've tried

```
{% set images %}
<img src="{asset:123:getUrl('transform')}" />
<img src="{asset:124:getUrl('transform')}" />
{% endset %}

{{ images|parseRefs|raw }}
```

But this just gives back the source urls and not the crops.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe a Reference Tag can not perform an image transform because it doesn't return an ElementCriteriaModel object.

I worked around this by using the craft asset id parameter:

```
    {% set assetSearch  = craft.assets.id(12651) %}

    {{assetSearch.first().getUrl('transform')}}
```

Comment: Great solution, thnx!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forgetting to loop through the images. If not could you be clearer in your question?

It should work like this:

```
{% for image in entry.imageHandle %}
    <img src="('{{ image.getUrl('transform') }}')" width="{{ image.getWidth('transform') }}" height="{{ image.getHeight('transform') }}');">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi justin,

I would like to use the reference tags. To do that I need to parse the var as explained in: [link](https://craftcms.com/docs/reference-tags)
But as I don't just want the url back, I don't get how to parse the code to also do an image transfrom.
Regards